# Find Interfaces of a Class using Reflections - Java

Tags: java, generics

We are trying to process classes with Annotations. What we would want to acheive is to retrieve the interfaces that the class implements along with its defined Types. This is required to cross check if the classes implement a certain interface and its corresponding Types.

Below is the code snippet

**Annotated Class**

```
@MyAnnotation(provider = "xyz")
public class MyAnnotatedClass implements
            MyAnnotationProvider<MyAnnotationRequestType, MyAnnotationResponseType, FaultType> {

     ...........
     ............

       }
```

**Processing Logic**

```
public class MyProcessorFactory extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (final TypeElement decl : annotations) {
        
        Set<? extends Element> elements = env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(decl);
        
        for (final Element element : elements) {
             
          Class<?>[] interfaces = element.asType().getClass().getInterfaces();
          
          for (Class<?> interfaceClass : classes) {
                
            <*Here I expect to access the my Interface **MyAnnotationProvider<MyAnnotationRequestType, MyAnnotationResponseType, FaultType>***> 
          }

        }
     }
  }
}
```

The interface object MyAnnotationProvider and its types MyAnnotationRequestType, MyAnnotationResponseType and FaultType are not accessible. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Generics get type erased during runtime. There is no way to access  them.

Comment: `element.asType().getClass()` does not return a class in the program.  It returns a Java SE class which is an implementation of TypeMirror.  You probably wanted something like `if (element instanceof TypeElement type) { Collection<? extends TypeMirror> = type.getInterfaces(); /* ... */ }`

Comment: Thanks @VGR. That helped a lot. With the TypeElement, I am able to get the Types from the TypeArguments. :)